# UIButton.contentEdgeInsets gets ignored when UIButton is in a vertical StackView with a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a problem with my UIKit Swift App. When using a vertical StackView with a UIButton and a UILabel, the contentEdgeInsets gets ignored. This only happens when the UIButton is inside the Stackview with a UILabel. When I remove the UILabel or use the exact same button outside of the StackView it works perfectly fine. I created a [example project](https://github.com/SkashEU/weird-stackview-example) to showcase the problem.

[Screen of the example project using following snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0LFQ.png)

```
exampleButtonInStackView.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
exampleButtonInStackView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
exampleButtonInStackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

exampleButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
exampleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 30
exampleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
exampleButtonInStackView.contentEdgeInsets = insets
exampleButton.contentEdgeInsets = insets
```

Comment: I think that the question should be self contained and not be dependent on the example project.

Comment: The example project is only for people who don't understand my question without it. I added all the code used to the question itself.

Comment: Layout debugger showed that the title label had some constraints that you had not added. This is weird indeed.

Comment: The question should be understandable without an example project. Also it's discouraged to link to examples etc. since the link could be obsolete/invalid in the future. Please consider what makes you believe what the question doesn't include all the information and add the information to the question instead.

Comment: And how exactly do you want me to include the storyboard into the question or what do you as an expert think is not understandable enough?

Comment: @Skash - I suspect you somehow got a corrupted storyboard file. I forked your project here: https://github.com/DonMag/weird-stackview-example and re-built your view controller from scratch. It doesn't show the same issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEmHp.png

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for your time! I cloned your fork but weirdly enough the error still appears for me

Comment: @Skash - did you run it without any edits?

Comment: @DonMag Yes it worked after the second try (idk, weird). I found the problem thanks to you. "Baseline Relative" was checked in my project. After unchecking the property, it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the problem thanks to DonMag's reply. The problem was the "Baseline Relative" property of the StackView. When this property is checked, the contentInsets gets ignored.